# Windows 10 OpenSSH - Character Encoding

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, openssh, character-encoding

Is there any setting on client-side such that I get the German Umlaut display correctly when connecting from my Win10, 64b, English to Linux servers by using Windows 10 OpenSSH client?

While I like Windows 10 OpenSSH client for connecting to my Linux servers, I do not get the character encoding set properly.

On Linux server-side, I am forced to make use of ISO-8859-1 (Latin1), en_US.

Can I set anything on client-side to make it work?

Using putty, German Umlaut are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need the answer, and I don't know if it'll help, but I had a problem that I think came from a misinterpretation of UTF8 by the Windows 1à version of openssh.

For a while, as a workaround, I used cygwin version of openssh (more specifically the one included in git-for-windows). I just kissed goodbye to my problem by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131654/using-utf-8-encoding-chcp-65001-in-command-prompt-windows-powershell-window/57134096#57134096).